# Calculate the number of days that the field value has not changed

Tags: postgresql, recursive

Please consider the following table:

| User | Date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1/1/2022 | 40 |
| John | 1/2/2022 | -30 |
| John | 1/6/2022 | 50 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| Jack | 4/1/2022 | 80 |
| Jack | 4/1/2022 | -60 |

We have three records for John and two records for Jack. In each of the dates, the user either added a value to the amount field (positive values) or subtracted from it (negative values).

> **The number of days that the sum of the amount has not changed is important**.

For example, from *1/1/2022* to *1/2/2022*, dear John had a value of 40. But on *1/2/2022*, the amount was reduced by 30. Therefore, for 30 days (from *1/1* to *1/2*), the amount was equal to 40, and again until *1/6*, the total amount (**40 - 30**) remained unchanged for about 120 days. And finally, until **today** (today is *8/23*), the sum of the amount will be equal to **40 - 30 + 50 = 60**.

---

#### Question:

- How can I calculate these intervals to get the number of days?
- How can you get these intervals for all users?

I read about Window or CTE but to no avail.

> **Why did I ask this question?**
>
> The number of database records has increased to about one million, and for 21,000 users, we must obtain
> the length of each interval and multiply it by the total amount of the
> previous records.

---

#### Expected Output:

For example, for John, I expect the following output:

```
40 × 30(days) + (40 - 30) × 60 (days) + (40 - 30 + 50) × 53 (days)
```

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Could you possibly update ([edit])your question and provide the community with an expected result set? This would greatly increase your possibility of receiving an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @JohnK.N. I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to answer your question, I did the following (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c6936b041c37f8053e513325009a5d09)):

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  t_user TEXT    NOT NULL,
  t_date DATE    NOT NULL,
  amount INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

populate:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES
('John', '2022-01-01',  40),
('John', '2022-02-01', -30),
('John', '2022-06-01',  50);
```

### First pass:

I've left in a couple of extra fields so that you can follow the logic - I've removed them for the final pass.

```
SELECT
  t_user, 
  t_date, 

  CASE
    WHEN LEAD(t_date) OVER w IS NULL
      THEN current_date
    ELSE LEAD(t_date) OVER w
  END AS ld,
  
  CASE
    WHEN LEAD(t_date) OVER w is null
      THEN current_date - t_date
    ELSE LEAD(t_date) OVER w - t_date
  END AS d_cnt,
  amount,
  
  SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY t_user ORDER BY t_date) AS rr_tot

FROM
  test
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY t_user ORDER BY t_date)
ORDER BY t_user DESC, t_date;
```

Result:

```
t_user      t_date          ld  d_cnt  amount  s_tot
John    2022-01-01  2022-02-01     31      40     40
John    2022-02-01  2022-06-01    120     -30     10
John    2022-06-01  2022-08-23     83      50     60
```

- `r_tot` (running total) keeps track of the total at each date range, necessary for the multiplication step (`r_tot * d_cnt`) in the final pass
- the `WINDOW w` clause is just a little syntactic sugar that (**really**) helps with legibility

### Final pass:

```
SELECT
  t_user, 
  SUM(r_tot * d_cnt)
FROM
(
  SELECT
    t_user, 
    CASE
      WHEN LEAD(t_date) OVER w is null
        THEN current_date - t_date
      ELSE LEAD(t_date) OVER w - t_date
    END AS d_cnt,
    amount,
    SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY t_user ORDER BY t_date) AS r_tot
  FROM
    test
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY t_user ORDER BY t_date)
  
) AS sub1
GROUP BY t_user
ORDER BY t_user;
```

Result:

```
t_user   sum
John    7420
```

A couple of points to note:

- please use [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates - that format is `YYYY-MM-DD` - it also makes your code more portable, universally understood and unambiguous. Standards are there for a reason and should be used unless you have a **very** good reason not to!
- in future, could you please provide a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) with your tables and data? This gives a single point of truth ([SPOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth)) for the question and saves on duplication of effort on behalf of those trying to help you
- don't use [keywords (and/or reserved words)](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words) like `Date` and `User` either as column or table names - it makes your SQL less portable and less readable and more error-prone